# Cassandra Select Query for List and Frozen

Tags: select, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I have user define type like

```
CREATE TYPE point ( pointId int, floor text);
```

And I have table like:

```
CREATE TABLE path (
id timeuuid,
val timeuuid,
PointList list<frozen <point>>,
PRIMARY KEY(id,val)
);
```

And have create index like

```
create index on path(PointList);
```

But the problem is I am not able to execute select query where PointList = [floor : "abc"].

I google for 2 hours but not able to find the hint.

I am using this query to execute select query

```
Select * from path where val = sdsdsdsdsds-dsdsdsd-dssds-sdsdsd and PointList contains {floor: 'eemiG8NbzdRCQ'};
```

I can see this data in my cassandra table but not able to get that data using above query.

I want select query where we can only use `floor` and `val`. Because we only have data for `floor and val`

I tried many different ways but nothing is working.

I would appreciate any kind of hint or help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

**Frozen point means point type is frozen, you can't partially provide point value, you have to provide the full value of point**

Example Query :

```
select * from path where pointlist CONTAINS {pointId : 1, floor : 'abc'};
```

Comment: Ohh Means I need to define all value of the frozen.

Comment: But I am using spring boot with cassandra and I only have data of floor. Is there any way that I can fetch data base using floor. ?

Comment: @ParthPatel Instead of using UDT, use separate field for pointID and floor, and then create index on floor

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but, thisi is just a sample. I have big list. and I only have data of `floor` . Can you tell me that, In Cassandra, is it possible to fetch data from the list the contain frozen datatype using where clause?